# entity framework - deleting full relationship for a single instance in N:N

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following class

```
public class ObjectA{
   private List<ObjectB> list;    
}
```

ObjectA and ObjectB are in N:N relation.
How do I delete all of the relation between the two?
It seems list.clear() doesnt do the work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the entities are attached to a context `list.Clear()` will do the work, for example:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var objectA = ctx.ObjectAs.Include("list").Single(o => o.Id == someId);

    objectA.list.Clear();

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list.Clear() works just fine in connected mode but it will require all B records belong to A pulled from database. Sometimes it may hurt the performance if there're too many B(rarely happens in practice). In that case, you can also use store procedure or context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from...") to manually remove the relationships in relation table.